# tensorflow GPU not showing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

### In terminal

- windows 10
- using cuda 10.1
- python 3.7.7
- GPU GeForce GTX 1050 4GB

```sh
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-07-08 17:10:50.005569: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2020-07-08 17:10:55.657489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 4.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2020-07-08 17:10:55.701387: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

### In jupyter notebook

```py
in [1]: import tensorflow as tf
        tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
out[1]: []

in [1]: tf.__version__
out[1]: '2.2.0'
```

Comment: are you using the same env to run the Jupyter notebook and the script?

Comment: yes, same anaconda env.

Comment: You may have 2 env, env (A) have a simple TF install and the second env (B) have GPU TF and your notebook is in env (A). did you install them in the anaconda base or a virtual environment?

Comment: i use same anaconda env name ai in both place and i check many time both env name ai  and no other env have install tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: Check that you Jupiter is running on the ai env then. You can do it in the Jupiter notebook or the anaconda navigator interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to make new kernel for this env and select kernel form jupyter notebook

```sh
$ conda activate env_name
$ pip install ipykernel --user
$ python -m ipykernel install --user --name env_name --display-name env_name
```